# WCF Client P12 certificate issue - Cannot resolve KeyInfo for verifying signature: KeyInfo 'SecurityKeyIdentifier'

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wcf-security, ws-security

I have the "Cannot resolve KeyInfo for verifying signature: KeyInfo 'SecurityKeyIdentifier" on my WCF service which is calling a java soap service. I made a lot of researchs, including Yaron recommendations but I'm stuck. I can reach the service, get a response because in fiddler or in a custom MessageEncoder I can see the service response but it fails in the next Authentication steps.

So this is my first configuration :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"/>
          <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" 
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"  
                    enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
                    requireDerivedKeys="false">
          </security>
          <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="******"
                              storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"
                              x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>

            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="******"
                                  storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"
                                  x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="***"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
        contract="****" name="***"
        behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior">
        <identity>
          <dns value="****"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I reproduce the call with soapui in order to compare the two envelopes.
So with an outgoing certificate I can get a response. This is the envelope :

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:test="******" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-1FA551D8E45A2519671568974431972170">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
         <ds:Signature Id="SIG-1FA551D8E45A2519671568974431981173" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
               <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                  <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa **** soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
               </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
               <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
               <ds:Reference URI="#id-1FA551D8E45A251967156896582764876">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="****" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                     </ds:Transform>
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                  <ds:DigestValue>09qV67e9HentqoNIEWQLkHmouOY=</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>pj9pg4JuAzlHAdz5mZmZOy+Et5voEnEUTzawfql4Qa7st3O2dxpa7z3x8ktPUvQb5UTQe4R7izMH
v4O43ZI7D0Mez0N8SvfaXTlA/mudk1GsdqvFYuOhayYJs0xeDHq7hIoB5WKbh7uTdPts+XZYHc1y
8zJk7oZhnNvHpwChh3A=</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-1FA551D8E45A2519671568974431973171">
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-1FA551D8E45A2519671568974431973172">
                  <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-1FA551D8E45A2519671568974431972170" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
         </ds:Signature>
      </wsse:Security>
      <wsa:Action>http://****/getserviceTest</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>uuid:aeafa280-18af-4f27-83a5-a0103bb9ce17</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:To>https://********</wsa:To>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-1FA551D8E45A251967156896582764876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <test:getserviceTestIn>
         <userInfo>
            <loginID>****</loginID>
            <passwordHash>dced489c01609dbfffc6c86461a69c629610dc1a</passwordHash>
         </userInfo>
      </test:getserviceTestIn>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the response :

```xml
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:exc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
   <S:Header>
      <Action S:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://*****/getserviceTestResponse</Action>
      <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:39624f81-e533-4cf4-b038-f05f40d2c17f</MessageID>
      <RelatesTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:aeafa280-18af-4f27-83a5-a0103bb9ce17</RelatesTo>
      <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</To>
      <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="_3" xmlns:ns16="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns15="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <wsu:Created>2019-09-23T02:53:44Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2019-09-23T02:58:44Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <ds:Signature Id="_1" xmlns:ns16="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns15="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
               <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                  <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse S"/>
               </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
               <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
               <ds:Reference URI="#_5002">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="S"/>
                     </ds:Transform>
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                  <ds:DigestValue>cDxxSUo0sUft403D3ftiRJMju0Y=</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
               <ds:Reference URI="#_3">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsu wsse S"/>
                     </ds:Transform>
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                  <ds:DigestValue>dTHkdp73Z3Wyyk4yagzPUn3ON+E=</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>VQo6HzqXDhVjK6su9JifYk6i+xNpCac0O9zmdCqQIJhQfBQlt5sCv4EuE6HveJPG4IjQpX9oKU5DYGCFtsYEmt+ClDrIORfsUbuXaQdvR8pA/t62vvGbcmAqsubqjz4uKKMnGJc5bOFvIPmkA5WIfieViutSQnGwA5xtK1PWt1k=</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                  <ds:X509Data>
                     <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=***, OU=***, O=**, C=**</ds:X509IssuerName>
                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>SERIAL IS DIFFERENT THAN MINE???</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                     </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                  </ds:X509Data>
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
         </ds:Signature>
      </wsse:Security>
   </S:Header>
   <S:Body wsu:Id="_5002">
      <ns2:GetserviceTestOut xmlns:ns2="http://******/">
         <reqID>d2f4c570-8a71-4d83-a427-fc0c40f150d4</reqID>
         <status>
            <status>0</status>
         </status>
         <node>
            <property1>*****</property1>
            <property2>*****</property2>
         </node>
         ...
      </ns2:GetserviceTestOut>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

What I saw in this response, it's the certificate X509SerialNumber is different than mine.

After creating a custom text encoder, I did some tests to generate the X509SerialNumber. My conclusion is that the client certificate p12 has 2 peer certificates one for server and one for client.

```
CipherSuite:
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
PeerPrincipal:
CN=XXXX, OU=XX, O=XX, C=XX
Peer Certificate 1:
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=XXX Server, OU=XX, O=XX, C=XX
Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
Key: Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Thu May 04 16:23:07 SGT 2017,
To: Sun May 02 16:23:07 SGT 2027]
Issuer: CN=XX Root Test CA, OU=XX, O=XX, C=XX
SerialNumber: [ 9c7b4731 23e73ea0]

]


Peer Certificate 2:
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=XX Root Test CA, OU=BrokWS, O=OZK, C=BG
Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

Key: Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Thu May 04 16:17:56 SGT 2017,
To: Sun May 02 16:17:56 SGT 2027]
Issuer: CN=XX Root Test CA, OU=XX, O=XX, C=XX
SerialNumber: [ e30bccb6 ec893986]

]
```

But wcf try to verify the signature with the client peer certificate and not the server certificate corresponding to the right X509SerialNumber in the reply from the server.

Do you have any idea how can I do with the wcf configuration ? Or maybe by extracting this peer certificates if it s possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: I find the solution myself by removing the security header from the reply. Because they only signed the timestamp and the body. And not the action, to, replyto, messageid.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution myself by removing the security header from the reply. Because they only signed the timestamp and the body. And not the action, to, replyto, messageid.

I did that with a custom MessageEncoder :

```
public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
        {
            byte[] msgContents = new byte[buffer.Count];
            Array.Copy(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, msgContents, 0, msgContents.Length);
            bufferManager.ReturnBuffer(buffer.Array);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(msgContents);
            var doc = new XmlDocument {PreserveWhitespace = true};
            doc.Load(stream);

            XmlNode envNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("S:Envelope")[0];
            XmlNode headerNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("S:Header")[0];
            XmlNode bodyNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("S:Body")[0];
            if (envNode.Attributes != null && bodyNode.Attributes != null)
            {
                envNode.Attributes.RemoveAll();
                headerNode.RemoveAll();
                bodyNode.Attributes.RemoveAll();
            }

            stream = new MemoryStream();
            doc.Save(stream);

            stream.Position = 0;
            return Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader.Create(stream), int.MaxValue, MessageVersion);
        }
```